# What are "stocks" called in English for online shops?

Tags: single-word-requests

In a piece of software, what would I call a place or building where products may be stored before their export or distribution for sale, particularly for online stores (such as Amazon.com)?

It will look like this:

> - Small Independent ****_*____*** has 200 item(s).
> - Books, Electronics and DVD/VCD products in the Medium Owned ****_*____***.

Comment: Why was the question downvoted? Edit: canceled vote.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was bumped, or how I ended up in this page, but this question makes no sense to me, even after substituting the accepted/suggested answers into the blank spaces in the provided example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit more information may help you select between the other answers.

A **warehouse** is any building used primarily to store goods.

A **distribution centre** is a warehouse typically used to dispatch goods in bulk to retail outlets. A distributor is distinct from a retailer (online or otherwise).

A **fulfillment centre** is a warehouse typically used to dispatch goods to individual consumers. It "fulfills" customer orders directly.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with ***[warehouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warehouse)***?

Answer (score 2):

How about fulfillment center ?

Answer (score 2):

[Distribution Centre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_center) includes warehouses and other buildings that perform this function.